# SQL Server Cast Decimal Data

Tags: sql-server

I have data amount in decimal(18,2) type, and currency char type

```
Currency    Amount
USD         1234.67
JPY         9876.00
```

I want to select data like this

> ```
> Currency    Amount
> USD         1234.67
> JPY         9876
> ```

I try to change data type to decimal(18,0) when currency is JPY, but it still get 2 decimal when currency is JPY
this is my SQL Code

```
CASE WHEN remitting_currency ='JPY' THEN CAST(SUM(c.amount) AS decimal(18,0)) ELSE CAST(SUM(c.amount) AS decimal(18,0)) END as amount
```

that code still get data like this

```
Currency    Amount
    USD         1234.67
    JPY         9876.00
```

is there another way? or what is wrong with my code?

Thank You

Comment: that is presentation issue. You can format the result the way you want in your front end application

Comment: what is a datatype of amount column in your table?

Comment: @Squirrel yes, i can get what i want when i work at front end, but i want to try it at my query
thank you

Comment: I agree with Squirrel that you should do this from the presentation layer. But if you insist: [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql), available since SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by casting accordingly, depending on the intended purpose of the Amount column.

Something like this perhaps

```
declare @table1 table(Currency varchar(100), Amount money)

INSERT INTO @table1
SELECT 'USD', 1234.67
UNION SELECT 'JPY',9876

SELECT  Currency, 
[Amount] = CASE 
            WHEN Currency='JPY' THEN cast(cast(Amount as int) as varchar(100)) 
            ELSE cast(Amount as varchar(100)) END 
FROM @table1
```

However, in principle, I agree with @Squirrel's comment that this is likely a presentation issue and should probably be satisfied there.

Comment: thank you, i already give try to @squirrel suggestion
and it's already done
i just want to learn something so i want to try at my query